# IF inside a SWITCH CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I got the following query :

```
SELECT      ua.attribute_id, ma.attribute_name, ma.attribute_type, ma.attribute_default, ma.attribute_format,
    (CASE ma.attribute_type
        WHEN 0 THEN ua.attribute_default
        WHEN 1 THEN ua.attribute_bool
        WHEN 2 THEN ua.attribute_combo
        WHEN 3 THEN ua.attribute_decimal
        WHEN 4 THEN ua.attribute_integer
        WHEN 5 THEN ua.attribute_decimal
    END) AS attribute_value 
FROM        units_attributes AS ua
LEFT JOIN   models_attributes AS ma ON ma.attribute_id = ua.attribute_id
WHERE       ua.unit_id = 1
```

I want to put a IF for `attribute_value`. If `attribute_value` is `NULL`, then I want to use `ua.attribute_default`.

I have attempted to use a IF statement after the AS but it doesn't work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using IF, try using [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). It takes multiple parameters and returns the first non-null value.

```
COALESCE(attribute_value, ua.attribute_default)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked like a charm ! Didn't know this function... sure does now ! Will remember it. Will mark as accepted in 10 minutes (I can't before). Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is there something similar if it's empty ? I guess I'll have to check if it's empty and if it does, I set to NULL. Can you confirm ?&

Comment: You can still use `COALESCE`, but on the parameter that could be an empty string, you should use [`NULLIF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif): `COALESCE(NULLIF(attribute_value, ''), ua.attribute_default)`

Comment: Nah, `attribute_type` will always be between 0 and 5. The function you gave me is fine here. I needed a way to check `WHEN X THEN Y`. If Y is NULL, I needed the default value instead.